# OutOfMemory Exception for background image of a layout

Tags: java, android, image, memory, bitmap

I am new to android  following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYy9adsIJDQ) tutorial  for creating a MEME application in android everything was working fine until I added image to my RelativeLayout background of a fragement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageOut">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/topText"
        android:id="@+id/topMemeText"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/bottomText"
        android:id="@+id/bottomMemeText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The error was

```
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 86687164 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
```

I know that this problem is due to image size and I have to decode it as there are many case as I searched online and here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html  .But everycase I came across use a ImageView but I have a background image of the layout rather than a ImageView so I how can I get the ImageView object from layout so that I can use.

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(
    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, 100, 100));
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the size in pixels of the image you are using?

Comment: the size is `262kb` I know if I use small size pic the prob might solve but how can I handle it with code with pixel its `1790 x 1757`

Comment: But what is the size in pixels (the dimensions of the image)?

Comment: @UdiI its `1790 x 1757`

Comment: In which Drawable is the image located and on which device did you try it?

Comment: i just added as a backgroud of my layout from the pic that I have in drawable folder amd I am on nexus 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the resizing of the image is causing your problem.

Try adding the image to drawable-xxhdpi and see if it helps.

If it doesn't try drawable-nodpi.

Comment: thaku you very very much wored with `drawable-xxhdpi` thank you for all your efforts it means alot I was trying this for days and it was so easy thanks you again .Can you explain why changing the folder worked I am just a beginner at this

Comment: Because the device you tried is xxhdpi, and the default base Android density is mdpi, so that caused the OS to do major resizing on an image which was already quite large.

Answer (score 0):

```
First get the bitmap 
Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, 100, 100);

Convert the bitmap to drawable as follows
Drawable mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

Finally you can use mDrawable to set your relative layout background
```

Comment: the other use solution worked for me but I was also trying your solution I am doing ` layout.setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);`  but this is depricated .I am new to this can you help

Comment: setbackground working above api level 16 and below setbackgrounddrawabale